# How return array(double[]) from com object in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, com

I return COM object in C# from C++ COM library. The object has a property that returns the type C# - **"object"**. The documentation indicated that its type is a **"Variant"**(in C++) and contains one-dimensional array of three **"double"** values​​. After making the cast,

```
Object obj = m.TextPosition;  // "m" - is com object
var d3 = (System.Double[])obj;// cast
```

I get the error: **"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[*]' to type 'System.Double[]'**.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a SAFEARRAY with a lower bound of 0 to be compatible with a .NET double[].

If that's not an option then you need to cast to Array in your C# code and use its GetValue() method to access the elements.  Use GetLowerBound() to know where to start.

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Aug/26/Accessing-a-SafeArray-Result-from-a-COM-Call-in-C

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me find a solution. Read more above.

Comment: Your answer gave me the solution space, from which to get what I needed was not difficult. That mean you answer was accurate for me. Thanks!